# How do I enable Spring support in Spring Tools 4 IDE?

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I've installed fresh Spring Tool Suite 4, but Spring support doesn't seem to be enabled. I.e.:

- There is no view "Spring Beans"
- Auto completion of class names or bean names doesn't work in Spring context xml files
- Ctrl+Click on a class name in Spring context xml file doesn't open the class

This worked out of the box in previous versions of STS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Tool Suite 4 is a major 'break with the XML past' of Spring. It is geared towards a more modern style of developing Spring applications using Spring Boot and Java annotations. As such, it no longer has support for the things you are referring too.

That being said, the old tooling is still available as an 'optional add-on' for the time being.  So you can still get those features back. Please refer to the STS 4 wiki [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/STS3-Features) for detailed information on how to install it.

PS: It is also still possible to get STS 3.9 as a 'self contained' distribution. And this will still receive maintenance updates until the middle of 2019. The download page is [here](https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all). You may also want to read the [STS 4 FAQ](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/FAQ) for some more info on the planned end-of-life for the old STS 3.x line.